# get number of days between two datetimes on a month level in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

Here is the dataset that contains when the person was assigned to a role, and has their and start date, and the year month in order for those months that they were in the role for:

```
  | ID | Name | strt_dt | end_dt | yearmo | 
  | 1  | Jay  | 4-22-19 | 7-30-19| 201904 | 
  | 1  | Jay  | 4-22-19 | 7-30-19| 201905 |  
  | 1  | Jay  | 4-22-19 | 7-30-19| 201906 |   
  | 1  | Jay  | 4-22-19 | 7-30-19| 201907 |  
  | 2  | Fao  | 7-14-19 |10-14-19| 201907 |    
  | 2  | Fao  | 7-14-19 |10-14-19| 201908 |   
  | 2  | Fao  | 7-14-19 |10-14-19| 201909 |   
  | 2  | Fao  | 7-14-19 |10-14-19| 201910 |
```

I was to calculate for each year-month the person was in the role, how many days of that month were they in the role. The output should look like this :

```
  | ID | Name | strt_dt | end_dt | yearmo | no_of days|
  | 1  | Jay  | 4-22-19 | 7-30-19| 201904 |  9 |
  | 1  | Jay  | 4-22-19 | 7-30-19| 201905 |  31|  
  | 1  | Jay  | 4-22-19 | 7-30-19| 201906 |  30|  
  | 1  | Jay  | 4-22-19 | 7-30-19| 201907 |  30| 
  | 2  | Fao  | 7-14-19 |10-14-19| 201907 |  18|  
  | 2  | Fao  | 7-14-19 |10-14-19| 201908 |  31|  
  | 2  | Fao  | 7-14-19 |10-14-19| 201909 |  30|  
  | 2  | Fao  | 7-14-19 |10-14-19| 201910 |  14|
```

I tried to extract the day they from the strt ( subtract it by 30 to get the no of ddays) and end date  and create a seperate column. But I am stuck on how to proceed from there. Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

```
df['strt_yearmo'] = df['strt_dt'].dt.year * 100 +df['strt_dt'].dt.month
df['end_yearmo'] = df['end_dt'].dt.year * 100 +df['end_dt'].dt.month


  | ID | Name | strt_dt | end_dt | yearmo | strt_yearmo|end_yearmo|
  | 1  | Jay  | 4-22-19 | 7-30-19| 201904 |  201904    |201907|
  | 1  | Jay  | 4-22-19 | 7-30-19| 201905 |  201904    |201907|
  | 1  | Jay  | 4-22-19 | 7-30-19| 201906 |  201904    |201907|  
  | 1  | Jay  | 4-22-19 | 7-30-19| 201907 |  201904    |201907 |
  | 2  | Fao  | 7-14-19 |10-14-19| 201907 |  201907    |201910 |
  | 2  | Fao  | 7-14-19 |10-14-19| 201908 |  201907    |201910 | 
  | 2  | Fao  | 7-14-19 |10-14-19| 201909 |  201907    |201910 |
  | 2  | Fao  | 7-14-19 |10-14-19| 201910 |  201907    |201910 |
```

Comment: How would you do this with pencil and paper?  Two of your partial-month answers are wrong -- did you check them to see how your arithmetic didn't work?  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: @ALollz, it would be 30 days for Jay in July. the end dt needs to be considered for calculating the number of days he stayed in that role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.select(condition, choice,alternative)`  after coercing the dates to datetime and extracting end month date in `yearmo`

Extract endmonth date frm yearmo

```
df['startmo']=pd.to_datetime(df['yearmo'].astype(str), format='%Y%m')+ pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
```

Coerce `strt_dt` and `end_dt` to date

`datedf['strt_dt'],df['end_dt']=pd.to_datetime(df['strt_dt']),pd.to_datetime(df['end_dt'])`

Come up with conditions

```
conditions=[df.startmo.dt.month==df.strt_dt.dt.month, df.startmo.dt.month==df.end_dt.dt.month]

#If month in yearmo is the same with strt_dt,substract strt_dt from endmont.
#If month in yearmo is the same with end_dt, extract the days in end_dt
```

Come up with Choices coresponding to each condition above

```
choices=[df.startmo.sub(df.strt_dt).dt.days+1,df.end_dt.dt.day]
```

Calculate the days by matching condition and choice. Include alternative as well. Here alternative is where  month in start and end does not match yearmo, it means the month is in the middle so just extract the days as  an alternative to the conditions

```
df['no_of days']=np.select(conditions,choices,df.startmo.dt.day)




ID Name    strt_dt     end_dt  yearmo    startmo  no_of days
0   1  Jay 2019-04-22 2019-07-30  201904 2019-04-30           9
1   1  Jay 2019-04-22 2019-07-30  201905 2019-05-31          31
2   1  Jay 2019-04-22 2019-07-30  201906 2019-06-30          30
3   1  Jay 2019-04-22 2019-07-30  201907 2019-07-31          30
4   2  Fao 2019-07-14 2019-10-14  201907 2019-07-31          18
5   2  Fao 2019-07-14 2019-10-14  201908 2019-08-31          31
6   2  Fao 2019-07-14 2019-10-14  201909 2019-09-30          30
7   2  Fao 2019-07-14 2019-10-14  201910 2019-10-31          14
```